# Можно ли потерпеть смерть?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, значение-слов, лексическая-сочетаемость

Из [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4_%D0%B8_%D0%AD%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4):
*Святые Эвальд и Эвальд, англосаксонские священники, один из которых по цвету волос известен был как «белый», другой — как «черный», в 625 году явились в Вестфалию для проповеди Евангелия саксам и **потерпели здесь мученическую смерть.***

Иссомневалась я в правильности этой фразы.
В [словаре глагольной сочетаемости непредметных имен](https://abstrnoun.academic.ru/3986) обозначено:
потерпеть аварию (крах, фиаско, поражение, неудачу).

Так грамотно, допустимо ли говорить — **потерпеть смерть**?

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, подразумевалось "претерпели".

> Его пророчество о том, что мессии суждено **претерпеть** мученическую смерть, приводятся в Евангелиях, по крайней мере, четыре раза. [Анна Нежинская. Никогда вы не воскреснете (2003) // Интернет-альманах «Лебедь», 2003.09.14]

"Стандартный" вариант: принять мученическую смерть.

Дополнение.

Похоже, я нашел первоисточник:

> [Эвальд](http://www.endic.ru/brokgause/Jevald-75228.html)
>    Эвальд (Ewald) — два англосаксонских священника; по цвету волос один известен был под именем "белого", другой под именем "черного". В 625 г. по Р. Хр. они явились в Вестфалию для проповеди Евангелия саксам и **потерпели** здесь мученическую смерть. Пипин Геристальский велел прах их похоронить в церкви Куниберта в Кельне. Они почитаются как св. патроны Вестфалии. Память их 3 октября. Ср. Mertens, "Die heiligen Ewald" (Кельн, 1879).
>    Энциклопедический словарь Ф.А. Брокгауза и И.А. Ефрона. — С.-Пб.: Брокгауз-Ефрон 1890—1907

Вот еще:

> Я иду в Рим, — сказал Христос, — вновь **потерпеть распятие** за тебя.

Похоже, это церковная лексика.

Answer (score 4):

Одно из значений слова "потерпеть" — пережить что-то неприятное. И в этом значении выражение "потерпеть смерть" вполне законно употребляется в христианской традиции, в которой смерть в определённом понимании есть один из неприятных, может быть, моментов вечной жизни. Употребляется и в наше время, хотя поиск больше находит старых книг.

Comment: Чисто книжное и в современной речи невозможно. Ни потерпеть смерть, ни пережить смерть.

Comment: @ddbug Речь идёт о так называемой православной литературе, в том числе современной.